# setVisibility of checkbox inside list fails after accessing textview in main activity

Tags: android, listview, android-view, visibility

In my `OnItemLongClick` ,  I need to set my visibility of checkbox from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`.

```
bookList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (!inSelectMode) {
                inSelectMode = true;
                myAdapter.setCheckMode(true);
                CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                if (checkBox.isEnabled()) {
                    checkBox.performClick();
                }
                int books = myAdapter.getCheckCount();
               // totalSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // totalSelected
               // .setText("You've selected " + ((books == 0) ? "no" : Integer.toString(books)) + ((books == 1) ? " book" : " books"));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Once I uncomment the `totalSelected.setVisibility()` the method `setCheckMode()` which contains the `checkBox.setVisibility()` doesn't work. There's no error, it just doesnt do anything.
`totalSelected` is a `textView` from my activity and `checkBox` is a `CheckBox` inside the row layout of my `ListView`. Is there some kind of problem when using these 2 views together(since one is in my activity.xml and the other is in my rowlayout.xml) ? If so How can I solve this issue?

relevant parts of my Adapter:

```
public void setCheckMode(boolean checkMode) {
    Log.d("setCheckMode :",checkMode?" true":" false");
    this.isCheckMode = checkMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(!checkMode){
        checker.isAnyChecked(false);
        checkCount = 0;
    }
}
```

-

```
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
     Log.d("bindView :", cursor.getString(1));

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    Log.d("BindView isCheckMode?:",isCheckMode ? "true" : "false");
    if(isCheckMode){
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("checkbox visibility :","visible");
    }
    else{
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("checkbox visibility","gone");
    }

    if (!isCheckMode){
        Log.d("setChecked :","false");
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: What is `totalSelected`?

Comment: it is the TextView showing the total number of checkboxes selected. it shows the user how many items they've selected which it gets from `myAdapter.getCheckCount()`. `myAdapter.getCheckCount()` seems to not affect the checkbox visibility